# Git LFS with Google Drive, Dropbox, etc?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, google-drive-api, dropbox, git-lfs

I'm working on a **game in Unity**, so my project contains **art assets**.
So I have to use **Git LFS**, but I will run out of that 1 GB quickly. (which is given by *BitBucket*. And that +1 GB is not so much and also costs a lot.)

Is there a way to store my **LFS content** on a **Google Drive, Dropbox**, some Azure service, or anything similar with **more than 1 GB capacity**?

(Dropbox is not preferred because the cheapest plan they afford is 1 TB and I think that that's a bit steep after a 2.5 GB free plan)

**EDIT:** I've just emigrated to ***GitLab***, because it offers 10 GB for free.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Just add it to e.g. GoogleDrive and ignore according stuff in `.gitignore`. However I'ld say this is not really coding related and therefore off topic here.

Comment: @derHugo: any link to an external resource: how to create a LFS storage on either a locally sync'd directory, or (better) directly on a shared dropbox directory, while minimizing risks of LFS repo corruption?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out this project:

https://github.com/sinbad/lfs-folderstore

It uses a Custom Transfer Agent to direct the files tracked by LFS to a different folder/service.

Answer (score 0):

You could sync as usual using onedrive, and place an additional folder for the assets that you need.
Then place a mklink (virtual folder link) in the unity project folder and .gitignore it.

That way you would have the benefits of the 2 world, all you need is to establish a do not edit/remove files rule. All users should do is add additional files, that they will be sync using onedrive and git for the rest.